# C# Temp Folder with session IDs

Tags: c#

I have an application that target .NET Framework 4.8. When using `%temp%` in File Explorer on a remote desktop machine I go to a path similar like this

`C:\Users\UserName\Local\Temp\6` where 6 is the session ID.

My problem is that `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` method returns this value without the session ID. In .NET 6 however it does return the value with the session ID.

Upgrading the project to .NET 6 is currently out of the question so I was wondering how else I could get around this?

My proposed solution is to determine if in a remote session using

```
[DllImport("user32")]
static extern bool GetSystemMetric(int indeX);
const int SM_REMOTESESSION = 0x1000;

var isRemoteSession = GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION);
```

and then I can combine the two using `Path.Combine()`

Is there any better solutions out there?

Comment: There's a policy setting to disable that session id creation altogether: https://serverfault.com/questions/1035959/windows-server-2019-windows-installer-temp-path-session-id Maybe an option?

Comment: @PMF Thanks for the idea, unfortunately different customers have different needs so this is also out of my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a remote machine to test out but I have used [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=net-6.0) to get full paths for strings containing path tokens.

See if that works for you.

```
string query = "%temp%";
string result = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(query);
```

This correctly returns `C:\Users\username\Local\Temp\2` on an Azure VM and `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp` on my local machine. I have also changed my Temp path in Environment Variables in Control Panel and it returns correctly.

Comment: Can confirm this works on .NET Framework 4.8, thank you very much! :D